# how to refresh a layout

Tags: java, android, layout

i want to remove added textfields and add other ones based on what is selected from a spinner. 
here is my code: 
in xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#f4f4f4"
android:id="@+id/taskoptionfragmentlinearlayout" > 


 <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select A Search Option" />
    <Spinner
       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/gis_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
         />  
    </LinearLayout>
```

in class:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)        
  {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasklist_options, container, false);

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
          ll = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.taskoptionfragmentlinearlayout);
            //create textfields....
            TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
            tv.setText(INPUTFLDLABELAArray.get(i));
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            tv.setTextSize(18);
            tv.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            tv.setPadding(0, 0, 15, 0);
            ll.addView(tv);
        }
```

i summarized the code to make it short.
so when an item in spinner is selected, the textfield shows. then when another item is selected, a textfield shows under the previous textfield. so what i want is to (refresh/reset) the layout so that every time an item is selected, the old textfield is removed and the new one is added.

Comment: What you need is probably just `ll.invalidate()`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()

Comment: i tried that (under the declaration of ll) but nothing changed

Comment: Under the declaration is too early, it has to be the last call of course, after you added the `TextView`. Also, if you want to replace views, you need to remove the old ones before adding: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViews()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try calling `ll.removeAllViews()` before adding the new ones

Comment: this works but this will remove also the spinner..and not only what  was added programatically.

Comment: i added back the spinner and everything else after calling ll.removeAllViews(). thank you

Comment: That's not very clean. Use another `LinearLayout` only for your `TextView` instead of the TextView without a wrapper. Then operate only on that container-layout.

Comment: Well, the appropriate way would be to have several different `Layouts` with different `EditTexts/TextViews` and show and hide them according to the spinner's listener using `View.setVisibility(VISIBLE/GONE)`.